# nextjs not using .env.development

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I am using NextJs 13.5.4.
I would like to get npm run dev to use the env file .env.development.local instead of .env.local

In the package.json file I  have tried:

```
"dev": "NODE_ENV=development next dev"
```

NextJS still uses .env.local

My .env files are:

```
.env.local
.env.development.local
.env.test.local
.env.production.local
```

It is not possible to use the below in next.config.js

```
env: {
    NODE_ENV: process.env.NODE_ENV,
},
```

Comment: next.js still uses `.env.local` because `.env.local` always overrides the default set. if you want to use `.env.development.local` then remove `.env.local`. And you don't need explicit about `development` mode, when you run `npx next dev` it automatically picks up the `.env.development.local` file and `npx next build` for the production env file. I think next.js 13.5 has introduced which env loading that shows in the console when you run `npx next dev` that's a huge DX.

Comment: Do you know how I would call npx next build to use .env.test.local instead of .env.production.local?

Comment: You could write a script in package.json like this `"test:build": "NODE_ENV=test next build"`. It will auto-pick up your `.env.test.local ` file. No extra config is needed.